# What if $|A+A|$ is proportional to $|A|^{1 + \delta}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $A$ be a finite subset of the integers and $0 < \delta \leq 1/2$. Suppose that $$|A+A| \asymp |A|^{1+\delta}.$$

What examples of such an $A$ are known? Can we conclude anything in general about the structure of $A$?

Comment: When searching for examples in additive combinatorics, it's usually best to look for examples in $\mathbb Z^n$. All these examples can be embedded to $\mathbb Z$ using a locally injective map $\mathbb Z^n \to \mathbb Z$. There are many different examples in $\mathbb Z^n$, which makes it seem unlikely to me one can say very much about the structure.

Comment: You can take a $k \times k \times \dots \times k$ hypercube and $\delta =\ln (2k-1)/\ln k - 1$, or you can take the product of an interval of length $|A|^{1-\delta}$ with a random set of size $A^\delta$, or the disjoint union of an interval of length $A$ and a random set of size $A^{\delta}$, or many things more complicated than these.

Comment: @WillSawin thanks for your comments. Your 3rd and 2nd examples are morally equivalent by the principle you mentioned in your first comment. Both of your sets are still like generalized arithmetic progressions.

Comment: I remember Freiman asking me this very question back to year 1981 or so... I am afraid we still cannot prove much, but for the examples of small doubling sets and discussion, you can check, for instance, Tom Sanders's "The structure theory of set addition revisited".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $|A+A|\le K|A|$, where $K$ does not grow with $A$ (or grows very slowly), we are in the realm of Freiman's Theorem: $A$ is densely contained in a generalized arithmetic progression. However, Freiman's Theorem (even with the best known quantitative bounds) says nothing when $K=|A|^\delta$, even if $\delta$ is small.

For small $\delta$, however, there is a fairly satisfactory answer due to Bourgain (as part of his quantitative sum-product and projection theorems, see [**Bourgain, Jean**. The discretized sum-product and projection theorems. *J. Anal. Math.* 112 (2010), 193--236.])

If $b\ge 2$ is a base and $A\subset \{0,1,\ldots,b^m-1\}$ is a set, then one can identify $A$ with a subset of the full $b$-ary tree of height $m$: the vertices at distance $j$ from the root are the intervals $[ k b^{m-j},(k+1) b^{m-j})$ which intersect $A$.

Bourgain proves the following: given $\varepsilon>0$, there are $\delta>0$, $b\ge 2$ (which can be taken as large as desired) such that the following holds if $m$ is large enough:

Suppose $A\subset \{ 0,1,b^m-1\}$ and $|A+A| \le b^{\delta m}|A|$ (which is the case if $|A+A|\approx |A|^{1+\delta}$). Then $A$ contains a subset $A'$ such that:

- $|A'| \ge b^{\varepsilon m}|A|$ (so $A'$ is a fairly dense subset of $A$).
- The $b$-ary tree associated to $A'$ is spherically symmetric, that is, any vertex of level $j$ has the same number $N_j$ of offspring.
- Furthermore, and this is the key point, for each $j$ either $N_j=1$ or $N_j \ge b^{1-\varepsilon}$. That is, at each level the tree has either no branching or close to full branching, uniformly over all vertices of that level.

Actually Bourgain deals with more flexible trees, but it is not hard to deduce the above formulation from his work, see Corollary 3.10 in my paper [On Furstenberg's intersection conjecture, self-similar measures, and the $L^q$ norms of convolutions, https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.07802 ].

Although the above structure theorem may appear to be rather weak at first sight, it does have powerful consequences, as shown by Bourgain and also in my paper referred above. Bourgain's initial approach in [**Bourgain, J**. On the Erdős-Volkmann and Katz-Tao ring conjectures. *Geom. Funct. Anal.* 13 (2003), no. 2, 334--365] consisted in applying Freiman's Theorem at many scales, but his more recent paper, cited above, has an elementary proof relying only on the Plünnecke inequalities. The dependence of $\delta$ on $\varepsilon$ is quantitative, and roughly exponential.

If $\delta$ is not very small, I don't think much is known. Examples are integer analogs of the ternary Cantor set: let $D\subset\{0,1,\ldots,b-1\}$ and let $A\subset [0,b^m-1]$ consist of all numbers whose base $b$ expansion has only digits from $D$. In many cases it is easy to calculate or estimate the size of $A+A$. For example, if $D=\{0,1,\ldots,c-1\}$ for $c<b/2$, then $A+A$ consists of all integers in $[0,b^m-1]$ whose base $b$ expansion has only digits from $\{0,1,\ldots,2c-2\}$, so that $|A|=c^m$ and $|A+A|=(2c-1)^m = |A|^{1+\delta}$ with $\delta\approx\log 2/\log c$. If $c$ is very large, then $A$ has the tree structure predicted by Bourgain's Theorem (without passing to a subset).

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer! A small typo there should be a negative sign in the exponent that appears in the first bullet.